# Infinite recursion in compileNodes using angularJS in IE8

Tags: internet-explorer, angularjs

I'm working on an Angular app, and it works great in all browsers save for IE8. IE7 and IE9 both work correctly.

I've been able to determine that angular's compileNodes function is recursing effectively infinitely. For testing purposes, I altered the compileNodes function to track depth and simply return at a certain threshold, and I confirmed that doing so allows the page to load and function correctly, so obviously this mass recursion should not be necessary for the page to function.

Obviously this is not a sustainable way to go about this, though, so I am wondering, has anyone else run into this behavior, and if so, were you able to find out what the problem was?

Edit: After some further debugging, I think I have narrowed it down to a custom directive we are using. The directive is really too long for it to be useful for me to paste it in here, but as I narrow it down to an exact piece, if I'm able to find something representative I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bunch more digging, I was able to determine the cause of the problem, at least enough for my purposes.

As mentioned in my edit, I had narrowed it down to have something to do with a custom directive called `form-field`. Through some trial and error, I was also able to determine that the issue occurred when a `date-picker` directive was on a child of the `form-field` element.

Whereas in most places this was being done something like

```
<div form-field>
    <date-picker></date-picker>
</div>
```

in once instance, the date-picker field was using a self-closing tag

```
<div form-field>
    <date-picker />
</div>
```

Apparently, `form-field`'s compilation couldn't handle this correctly and managed to enter an infinite loop, and I'm guessing it only happened in IE8 because other newer browsers silently interpreted the self-closing tag as having a defined start and end tag.

Long story short, I changed the self-closing tag, and everything works correctly now.